# Solving the following ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I came up with the following ODE:

$\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{dy}{dt}=k_1(a-x-y)(b-x)+k_2(a-x-y)(c-y)$

where $k_1,k_2,a,b,c$ are constants. I know under changes of variable, the equation can be changed into the following form:

$\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{dy}{dt}=k_1(a-x-y)x+k_2(a-x-y)y$

which is simpler. But I can't go any further. Hope someone could help. Thanks!

Comment: What is $x$ and $y$. Do they depend on each other?

Comment: They are functions depend only on time $t$.

Comment: Set $u=x+y$ and $v=y-x$ and then eliminate $x$ and $y$ from the equation. $v$ is an unspecified and unbound free function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $k_1=k_2 = k$ we have

$$
(x+y)' = k(x+y)(a-(x+y))
$$

now making $u=x+y$

$$
u'=k u(a-u)\Rightarrow x+y = \frac{a e^{a c_0+a k t}}{e^{a c_0+a k t}-1}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Starting from your simplification:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{dy}{dt}=k_1(a-x-y)x+k_2(a-x-y)y$$

$$\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{dy}{dt}\;=\left[k_1x(a-x-y)+k_2y(a-x-y)\right]$$

$$\int\left(dx+dy\right)=\int\bigg(ak_1x+ak_2y-k_1x^2-k_2yx-k_1xy-k_2y^2\bigg)dt$$

$$x+y=\int\bigg(ak_1x+ak_2y-k_1x^2-k_2yx-k_1xy-k_2y^2\bigg)dt$$

We cant integrate  $x$ and $y$ wrt. $t$ because they implicitly depend on $t$.

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are by context as dynamic variables not constant.